# Spring MVC exception handler doesn't work with additional custom interceptor

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, aop

I have one Spring MVC controller, and I intercept all the controller method with AOP in XML file to monitor the execution time. With this customer AOP, I find that the ExceptionHandler can not work. it always return http code 200 and has this error message:

```
"XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal".
```

Below is my AOP configuration and the ExceptionHandler method

AOP configuration:

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="commonPointcut"
                  expression="execution(* com.xxx.xxx.controller.*.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="commonPointcut" advice-ref="multiTenantInterceptor" />
    <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="commonPointcut" advice-ref="executionTimeInterceptor" />
</aop:config>
```

ExceptionHandler:

```
@ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
public ModelAndView exp(MyException ex) {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("error");
    model.addObject("message", ex.getMessage());
    return model;
}
```

Is there anything wrong? Thanks.